# Finding value for convergence

Tags: analysis

For which positive real numbers b is $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{\sin k}}{k^{b}} $$
convergent?

I was thinking that I could use the ratio test, to deduce a inequality?
So if I use the ratio test I end up with:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} (2^{\sin(k+1)-\sin(k)})\cdot\left({\frac{k}{k+1}}\right)^{b} < 1 $$

I don't know how to expand this, or if I am even on right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use the [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test#Statement) for series observing that
$$
\frac12 \cdot \frac1{k^{b}} \le \frac{2^{\sin k}}{k^{b}} \le 2\cdot\frac1{k^{b}} 
$$ then one may conclude with $p$ series results.

Comment: Sorry, but how do we get these inequalites? And I am not sure I get why those inequalites hold?

Comment: @fejz1234 I've used that $-1 \le \sin k \le +1 \implies \frac12=2^{-1} \le 2^{\sin k} \le 2$.

Comment: @fejz1234 Then the initial series is convergent *iff* $p>1$.

Comment: Okay but in which way? I cant figure it out? Edit: the implication-step is where im confused

Comment: @fejz1234 Are you Ok with my first comment above?

Comment: Im ok with −1≤sink≤+1 .. after that Im kinda lost.

Comment: Ah okay now I see it.

Comment: So then b has to be bigger then 1 in order for it to converge?

Comment: @fejz1234 Exactly.

Comment: Could you help me with a similar exercise?

Comment: @fejz1234 If you type 'comparison test' in the 'Q&A search' above you will get many interesting exercises.